# Printk behaviour change with early_printk enabled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

Normally `printk` does not print any messages before `console_init` which is present in `start_kernel`. But with `early_printk` enabled, `printk` starts printing messages before console initialization. Now how does this behaviour of `printk` change since I am still using `printk` function to print debug messages and not `early_printk` function. How is this mapping done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a mapping. When `early_printk` is enabled, the same `printk()` is used as before, just new boot console is being registered in that case, and `printk()` uses it on early boot stages.

Look at [arch/arm/kernel/early_printk.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/early_printk.c). You can see that:

- new console being registered with `register_console()` function
- that console has `CON_BOOT` flag, so it's unregistered automatically as soon as real console is registered
- printing happens via `early_write()` function, which in turn uses `printch()` function, which implemented for each platform separately

> Where in kernel source the `early_console` is disabled after kernel console initialization?

It's done in [register_console()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2740) function:

```c
if (bcon &&
    ((newcon->flags & (CON_CONSDEV | CON_BOOT)) == CON_CONSDEV) &&
    !keep_bootcon) {
        /* We need to iterate through all boot consoles, to make
         * sure we print everything out, before we unregister them.
         */
         for_each_console(bcon)
             if (bcon->flags & CON_BOOT)
                 unregister_console(bcon);
}
```

All boot consoles are disabled by `unregister_console()` function in code above (when real console is being registered).

> And where is the real console getting registered?

Real consoles use the same method for registration -- `register_console()` function. For example:

- from my board's defconfig file ([arch/arm/configs/omap2plus_defconfig](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/configs/omap2plus_defconfig#L216)) I can see that my board is using `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250` as real console
- we can search where `register_console()` is executed in my serial driver; it's done in [univ8250_console_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_core.c#L683) function

> Is there any way to keep **boot consoles** up after console initialization and **disable real console**?

Boot consoles are automatically unregistered only when real console is registered. Following this logic, you just need to disable the real console in order to keep boot console intact.

So what you need to do, is to find out which exactly driver is used for real console in your case. You can do that looking into your `.config` file, or the `*_defconfig` file for your board. Once you located it, just disable that driver in configuration and rebuild the kernel.

If after doing so you keep observing the registering of some real console, you need to add some debug printings to `register_console()`, to figure out what driver is being registered, and then disable it in your configuration.

Comment: I registered my function to `mcount` similar to ftrace and used the printk there to print function name but no output is seen .But directly if I give printk in `start_kernel` function  it works.What might be the reason? And even `printk("%pS", __builtin_return_address(0));` gives only hexadecimal value when printed in `start_kernel` function and nothing gets printed if I write the same statement inside some function of `start_kernel` such as inside `tick_init`.

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with fact that boot console is in use (i.e. `earlyprintk` enabled). Try to `printk()` some regular text, like `"hello"`, and if it works, then your issue is connected with `printk()` format. Read [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) for details. If you still concerned, you should ask another question on SO, like "Why printk() print only function address for `%pS` format".

Comment: Where in kernel source the `early_console` is disabled after kernel console initialization?

Comment: I added the answer to your question to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to use my boot console even after console initialization. So i removed CON_BOOT flag from early_printk.c but I get this error `error: request for member ‘index’ in something not a structure or union
  .index = -1,
  ^` .I know this is the wrong way but is there any way to keep **boot consoles** up after console initialization and **disable real console** ?

Comment: And where is the real console getting registered? I could not find it.

Comment: Check my original answer, I added some info there.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm curious, why do you want to stick with boot console and don't want to use the real one?

Comment: I am trying to debug using early printk and want to use the same  after console initialization. And by chance do you happen to know about imx7 dual 's driver? Thank you

Comment: Yes, but why you don't want to use real console? As for your imx7 question: look into your `defconfig` file (probably `arch/arm/configs/imx_v6_v7_defconfig`). Try to disable all `CONFIG_SERIAL_*` definitions (make them `# ... is not set`). Reconfigure and rebuild your kernel, and see if it helps.